# Stable framing as a classifying space?

Tags: algebraic-topology

A stable framing is a stable tangential structure $\mathcal{X} = EO \to BO$ (ref. Dan Freed's [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture9.pdf) Exercise 9.50).  Can it be represented as the classifying space $BG$ of the colimit of some sequence of Lie groups $G = \text{colim}_{n\to\infty}{G(n)}$?  This is Exercise 10.31 in Dan Freed's [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture10.pdf).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan; really! But Dan Freed claims that it is a stable tangential structure.  See his Exercise 9.50 (link is given above).  Did I understand his phrasing completely wrong?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: in fact I would be very grateful if you could give an interpretation in your way (your comment) for other tangential structures like spin structure.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by "stable tangential structure": you just mean a map to $BO$. You can take each $G(n)$ to be the trivial group; $EO$ is contractible.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: if I understand your answer correctly I can let $G(n)$ be any trivial group because any contractible space can serve as $EO$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: many thanks Qiaochu!